# GeoDjango 'NoneType' error when using 'distance' function

Tags: python, geodjango

I have a site that's working on our staging server but after copying it to the live server I am getting the following error when trying to perform a distance() call (code cut down to minimum)

```
>>> Buddy.objects.all().distance(pnt[0].geom, field_name='postalcode__geom')                                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/query.py", line 100, in distance
    return self._distance_attribute('distance', geom, **kwargs)
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/query.py", line 582, in _distance_attribute
    geodetic = geo_field.geodetic(connection)
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 131, in geodetic
    return self.units_name(connection) in self.geodetic_units
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 122, in units_name
    self._get_srid_info(connection)
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 108, in _get_srid_info
    self._units, self._units_name, self._spheroid = get_srid_info(self.srid, connection)
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 35, in get_srid_info
    units, units_name = sr.units
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base.py", line 281, in units
    return (self.linear_units, self.linear_name)
  File "/home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base.py", line 253, in linear_units
    return m.group('unit')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

>>> pnt[0].geom
<Point object at 0x1fb0370>
```

I've been unable to find any information elsewhere this error. Any help as to what might be causing this would be very welcome.

**EDIT**

Not having a clue what I'm doing, I've come up with possibly the best patch in the world /s

```
--- /home/buddyup/base.py       2012-01-18 22:17:04.000000000 -0500
+++ /home/buddyup/sites/buddyup/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base.py      2012-01-18 22:16:09.000000000 -0500
@@ -239,7 +239,8 @@
             return None
         else:
             m = self.units_regex.match(self.wkt)
-            return m.group('unit_name')
+            return 'meter'
+            #return m.group('unit_name')

     @property
     def linear_units(self):
@@ -250,7 +251,8 @@
             return None
         else:
             m = self.units_regex.match(self.wkt)
-            return m.group('unit')
+            return 'm'
+            #return m.group('unit')

     @property
     def angular_name(self):
```

I have no idea why it is unable to find the units or the units name, but for now that works for me. I would love to hear what the actual problem could be and find a valid solution.

**EDIT 2**

```
yum install gdal
```

After talking to pizzaparty in the #django IRC channel he pointed out that installed gdal should stop Django trying to get the units from a Point object that doesn't have any. That seems to be a much better solution.

Comment: Post the EDIT 2 as an answer instead of as part of the question :)

Comment: @FranciscoPuga done. Is there any advantage to adding it as an answer instead of an edit?

Comment: It's just a good practice. The questions will appear as solved if you search for it, others users can vote your answer, ... And it's easy to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install gdal
```

After talking to pizzaparty in the #django IRC channel he pointed out that installed gdal should stop Django trying to get the units from a Point object that doesn't have any. That seems to be a much better solution.

http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base.py

You can read the TODO there about how GDAL is highly recommended for distance queries.